# Display WooCommerce products in specific order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sql-order-by

I need to display WooCommerce products in a specific order by listing the SKU's/ID's. Either using a shortcode or a custom loop.

For example I want to show the following products in this exact order:

`[products ids="1,3,2"]`

I cannot use menu order because the order will be different depending on page:

Page 1:
`[products ids="1,3,2"]`

Page 2:
`[products ids="3,2,1"]`

I have tried the below suggestion, but it doesn't seem to change anything:

`[products ids="1,3,2" orderby="post__in"]`

The products still come through in the default order.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the woocommerce default product by extending like that -

```
add_shortcode( 'custom-products-ordering', 'custom_products_ordering_callback' );

function custom_products_ordering_callback( $attr ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $orderby = $attr['orderby'];
    $columns = $attr['columns'];
    $limit = $attr['limit'];
    $paginate = $attr['paginate'];
    
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    
    $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post.`ID` FROM `wp_posts` AS post, `wp_postmeta` AS postmeta WHERE post.`ID` = postmeta.`post_id` AND post.`post_type` = 'shop_order' AND postmeta.`meta_key` = '_customer_user' AND postmeta.`meta_value` = '".$current_user_id."'");   

    foreach( $query as $key => $value ){
         $filter = $value->ID;
    }
  
    $product_ids_str = implode( ",", $filter );
   
    return do_shortcode("[products ids='".$product_ids_str."' columns='".$columns."' limit='".$limit."' paginate='".$paginate."' orderby = '".$orderby."']");
}
```

How you use is -

```
[custom-products-ordering column="4" limit="12" paginate="true" orderby="post__in"]
```

You can extend or sort anything you want by modifying the query.